# How to access a part of a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to access some data and keep getting errors no matter what I try. Please help.

`"rain":{"3h":13.625}` is the part of the JSON file I am trying to access.

Here is what I have tried:

`var currentRain = data.rain.3h;`   Which is most logical as it worked before but the number is what is giving the error.

`var currentRain = data.rain["3h"];`
 `var currentRain = data.rain[0]["3h"];`
 `var currentRain = data.rain["3h"][0];`

**UPDATE:**

This is the JSON payload:

```
{ "base" : "stations",
  "clouds" : { "all" : 92 },
  "cod" : 200,
  "coord" : { "lat" : -33.850000000000001,
      "lon" : 151.22
    },
  "dt" : 1429558616,
  "id" : 6619279,
  "main" : { "grnd_level" : 1024.97,
      "humidity" : 100,
      "pressure" : 1024.97,
      "sea_level" : 1031.0999999999999,
      "temp" : 288.77699999999999,
      "temp_max" : 288.77699999999999,
      "temp_min" : 288.77699999999999
    },
  "name" : "City of Sydney",
  "rain" : { "3h" : 13.625 },
  "sys" : { "country" : "AU",
      "message" : 0.0101,
      "sunrise" : 1429474880,
      "sunset" : 1429514809
    },
  "weather" : [ { "description" : "heavy intensity rain",
        "icon" : "10n",
        "id" : 502,
        "main" : "Rain"
      } ],
  "wind" : { "deg" : 157.5,
      "speed" : 8.3200000000000003
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your (whole) JSON?

Comment: And how you are parsing the JSON into the `data` object

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":151.22,"lat":-33.85},"sys":{"message":0.0101,"country":"AU","sunrise":1429474880,"sunset":1429514809},"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":288.777,"temp_min":288.777,"temp_max":288.777,"pressure":1024.97,"sea_level":1031.1,"grnd_level":1024.97,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":8.32,"deg":157.5},"clouds":{"all":92},"rain":{"3h":13.625},"dt":1429558616,"id":6619279,"name":"City of Sydney","cod":200}

Comment: `data.rain["3h"]` is working fine in chrome console for `data={"rain":{"3h":13.635}}`

Comment: I just pasted into JSBeautifier, are there some odd characters in there? Or is that just a copy/paste problem? `"h‌​umidity"` and `13.635` they appear.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `["bracket notation"]` to access this, since `"3h"` begins with a number. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explains:

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct JSON:

```
{
   "rain": {
      "3h": 13.625
   }
}
```

First you need to parse it and transform into an object:

`var jsonToObject = JSON.parse('{"rain":{"3h":13.625}}');`

You can now access it like this:

`jsonToObject.rain["3h"]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `data["rain"]`. If you need to parse it first do `JSON.parse(data)` and then `data["rain"]`.

**OUTPUT**

```
console.log(data["rain"]);
> { '3h': 13.625 }
```

...keep in mind that will return an Object.